# RecyclerView nor updating in notifyItemInserted or in notifyItemRemoved

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am inserting value to RecyclerView by following way

```
public class UserListFragment extends Fragment implements UserEvents {


    private View rootView;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<User> mUserList;

    RoomOrUserRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;


    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        UserListFragment f = new UserListFragment();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_list_fragment, container, false);   
        findViews(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void findViews(View view) {

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mUserList = ((SocketApplication) mActivity.getApplication()).getUserListExcludeMineId();

        if (mUserList != null && mUserList.size() > 0) {

            adapter = new RoomOrUserRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), mUserList, null);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        ((SocketApplication) mActivity.getApplication()).setmUserEventsInterface(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserLeft(int position) {
        if (position != -1) {
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
            adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mUserList.size());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserJoin(final User user) {
        mUserList.add(user);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(mUserList.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

but that item is not inserted or I am showing nothing update in UI

can anybody help me how to resolve this issue

when ever new user inserted or deleted this UserEvents interface's method will be execute

```
 @Override
        public void onUserLeft(int position) {
            if (position != -1) {
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mUserList.size());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserJoin(final User user) {
            mUserList.add(user);
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(mUserList.size() - 1);
        }
    }
```

but do not know why Recycler is not updating

Below is screenshot my debugger point

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jraNx.png

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code? I try this code my project and works.

```
@Override
        public void onUserLeft(final int position) {
            if (position != -1) {
                        mUserList.remove(position);
                        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position,1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserJoin(final User user) {
                    mUserList.add(user);
                    adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(mUserList.size()-1,1);
        }
```

Comment: Nothing happen brother, I have debug my app that pointer is coming over there but UI is not updating

Comment: @user2401268 ok, i try again bro.

Comment: Can you try again bro?

Comment: Ok let me try this one

Comment: I have tried your code bro but nothing happen still remaining as same

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mUserList.remove(position);
recycler.removeViewAt(position);
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);                 
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mUserList.size());
```

Comment: Thanks brother but if it is correct then what about add

Comment: post where you are calling `onUserLeft`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this after remove or add.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 });
```

Comment: Nothing happens :( can not find solution what is the issue